# No Network connection over Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 ( dual boot win10) all was perfect until the next day im having issue with my wifi connection. I see the wifi, i put in password all is good but no connection.
I get a "?" In the notification bar. I have no problems with a wired connection.
I check a few post with no succes :
Networkmanager.conf 
Dhclient -r

Any idea?

Thanks
Jeff